# Domain object string list - Adding on the fly

Tags: string, grails, dns, persistence

Maybe this is an issue with persistance and the domain object. So I have a list of manual notes that can be added to a person. My person class looks similar to this (I've wrapped the object in transients to ignore persistence):

```
class Person {
...
List<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>()
...
}
```

When I update a person with a note (textfield on view will allow note to be added), I want to do something simple like adding the new note to the array list tied to the person:

```
class PersonController {
...
def update() {
    def contactInstance = Contact.get(params.id)
    if (!contactInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (params.version) {
        def version = params.version.toLong()
        if (contactInstance.version > version) {
            contactInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this Contact while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [contactInstance: contactInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    contactInstance.properties = params

    /**
     * Check for inactive - Then flag with user and date tag
     */
    if(params.isActive == null) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        contactInstance.properties.isActiveNote = "Made inactive by " + session.user + " on " + dateFormat.format(date) + "."
    }

    /**
     * Date stamp of the note itself
     */

    if(params.notes.equals("")) {}
    else {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        //contactInstance.properties.notes = contactInstance.properties.notes + "    " + params.notes + " - (" + dateFormat.format(date) + " " + session.user + ");"
        contactInstance.allThese.add(contactInstance.properties.notes)
        println(contactInstance.allThese)
    }


    if (!contactInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [contactInstance: contactInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'contact.label', default: 'Contact'), contactInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: contactInstance.id)
}
...
}
```

The call to update from my gsp:

```
<g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code:'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
```

But it just seems to store the array with a single note. Is there a persistance issue with Grails domain objects and collections? It could very well be a simple issue on my end!

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This example uses a one to many relationship between an author and a book: http://www.2paths.com/2009/10/01/one-to-many-relationships-in-grails-forms/                                                                        I want to do something similar, but obviously not with book objects. Instead I want to use String typed notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view includes multiple `<input>` fields or `<textarea>`s with the same name ("notes", to match the field name in your Domain class), Grails will automatically bind the values to your `notes` array.

You might also look into the new `params.list()` method that would allow you to iterate through request parameters and then add them individually to your array.

Comment: I should be clear - I renamed my list here to notes for the sake of simplicity. It's really named allThese for now.

Comment: Does your request include a param (or multiple params) named "allThese", or just "newNote"?  And, does your domain object have a transient named "newNote"?  If not, you might just need to change `person.notes.add(person.properties.newNote)` to `person.notes.add(param.newNote)`

Comment: I updated my question. I don't have a request including anything. I have a hidden field with the call to upload that includes the ID of the contact that I am updating.

Comment: Try changing: `contactInstance.allThese.add(contactInstance.properties.notes)` to `contactInstance.allThese.add(params.notes)`

Comment: No luck - It's acting as a single count arraylist. I feel like there is an issue with this collection and GORM, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: So I think I figured out the solution. I created a has many relationship: static hasMany = [allNotes: String]. When I use your line above after that create (GORM sets up relational table), I see that my contact is updating with each of the notes I add. So I think that's how I do it?

Comment: Strange, sorry to send you in circles. I don't see it in your snippets, I wonder if you need to add a hasMany? `static hasMany = [ notes: String ]`  A little more detail here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCollectionTypes

Comment: You're exactly right Andrew. I had to refactor similar to that example. No worries about the circles (part of learning, I love it) - you were very helpful. Thanks again - Looks like I've got this working now!